# Animate div Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Jquery code for hiding and showing a div on click

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#parapic1').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para1').show();
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para2').attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para3').attr('style', 'display:none;');
    });

    $('#parapic2').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para1').attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para2').show();
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para3').attr('style', 'display:none;');
    });

    $('#parapic3').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para3').show();
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para2').attr('style', 'display:none;');
        $(this).closest("#maincontainer").find('.para1').attr('style', 'display:none;');
    });
});
```

Now I am wondering how I can `hide` and `show` it by adding some animation to it like `left-right` or any other good animation.

Thank You :)

Comment: I am new to jquery so please don't mind if it some foolish question. Thanks

Comment: Off-topic comment, but you could definitely re-factor that code so you don't have 3 click functions. What happens if you add in another 3 paragraphs for example, the code could get pretty long.

Comment: @Richa ,Ruchya ,Please check link http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @NickR Any help how do i make it short??

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS too.

Comment: You don't need to combine .closest() with IDs (#) - IDs are *unique*, i.e. there can only be ONE #maincontainer item in your document. Maybe that's a problem - check if you have set several id="" attributes in your HTML.

Comment: take a look to http://api.jqueryui.com/show/

Comment: @user3401335 , i told her so.

Comment: @sb. I have just one element with #maincontainer. Is using closest wrong???

Comment: It's not wrong, only needlessly complicated. You could replace `$(this).closest("#maincontainer")` with just `$("#maincontainer")`.

Comment: Well, it searches for the 'closest of a type x' - if your type is unique, there is no need to search for it. You can select it directly and without any trouble via $('#maincontaner')

Comment: "Now I am wondering how I can hide and show it by adding some animation to it like left-right *or any other good animation*." - this question appears to be off topic as **too broad** since there are too many possibilities. please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do when working with a library (doesn't matter which language), is to make yourself familiar with the documentation. If you check out http://api.jquery.com/hide/ you can see that you can pass different parameters that alter the function's behaviour. For example, if you want the animation to last 2 seconds, you can do:

```
$('#myId').hide(2000);
```

If you want to work with cooler effects, maybe you should go and check out jQuery UI, it adds stuff such as

```
$('#myId').hide('blind');
```

See http://jqueryui.com/effect/

PS: As I stated in my comment above, you should also have a look at different methods for selecting stuff. As there can only be one id, $(this).closest('#id') doesn't make sense at all :)

I hope that that's somewhat helpful :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the different jquery animations to animate this:

```
$('#parapic1').click(function () {
        $('.para').fadeIn();

    });
```

To control the speed of the animation:

```
$('#parapic1').click(function () {
            $('.para').fadeIn('fast');

        });
```

[This article explains slides very well](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/)
[Demo of jquery animations](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/kDL8C/)

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and powerful jQuery method for motion is .animate() (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). With it, you can animate many CSS properties including opacity, position (left, right, top), size, etc.

While there are other shortcut methods, such as fadeOut/fadeIn (http://api.jquery.com/fadein/), and slideDown (http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/), which are useful for quick time-saving animations, .animate() will be the most flexible.

jQuery Animate Syntax Example

```
$(parent).click(function() {
    $(child).animate({left: 50, opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
```